# one more step needed in a proof and I cannot figure it out

Tags: real-analysis

$S_n$ is a sequence, and $S_{m_k}$ is a subsequence of $S_n$. Suppose $S_n>b \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $b \in \mathbb{N}$.
Here is some steps I use in the proof of something.
$S_n > b \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\implies S_{m_k} > b \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$
$\implies S_{m_k} - b >0$ $\implies \lim{(S_{m_k} - b)} \geq 0$

for the last implication, I think it is trivial but my professor said it's not that trivial and some proof needed here and I couldn't figure it out, can someone help me out with this. I'm taking my first mathematical analysis class this semester.

Here is the original question:

> A sequence $(S_n)$ satisfies $S_n < a$ for all even $n$, and $S_n >b$ for all odd $n$, where $a < b$. Prove that $(S_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

The way I approach this is if I want to show a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, then it is the same thing to show it is a convergent sequence.
So for the sake of contradiction, assume $(S_n)$ is a convergent sequence.
This would imply that every subsequence of $(S_n)$ is a convergent sequence with a limit same as $S_n$
Only consider the odd part now, denote $S_{m_k}$ as a subsequence that contains all the odd terms of $S_n$, where $m_k = 2k-1 , k \in \mathbb{N}$, then I use the proof I state above.

Comment: You don't give much context to go on. For one thing, it's not obvious that $S_{m_k} - b$ must have a limit at all.

Comment: Assuming you have convergence, suppose for contradiction that the limit is strictly less than zero. What would this imply?

Comment: oh wait let me type in the whole question

Comment: Hint: $|S_{n+1} - S_n| \gt b - a$ for $\forall n$.

Comment: @Glare If I assume $lim(S_{m_k} - b) <0$, I can end up with $lim S_{m_k} <b$, so how can I get a contradiction?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, if a sequence is cauchy it is to be convergent. So if $m_k=2k-1$ then $\lim{S_{m_k}}\ge b$ and if $m_k=2k$ then $\lim{S_{m_k}}\le a$ where $a<b$. Since every subsequence of a convergent sequence should converge to the same point, we do not have a convergent sequence and hence not cauchy.

Comment: @SeanZhou If the limit is strictly less than $b$, look for some $\epsilon$ so small that the points of the sequence are less than $b$. This will give you the contradiction you're looking for. (Try $\epsilon = (b-L)/2>0$, where $L$ denotes the limit). That being said, I think the other responders have given a much cleaner proof of the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Cauchy sequence requires the all the terms to be within an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ of each other if you choose a sufficiently large $n$.

For your sequence, however, if we choose $\epsilon < b-a$, then

$$|S_{n+1} - S_n| > b-a > \epsilon$$

for all $n \in \Bbb N$, so it cannot be Cauchy.

---

If you want to use contradiction, let $x_n$ be the even terms and $y_n$ be the odd terms of $S_n$, which we will assume converges to a limit $L \in \Bbb R$.

Then $x_n$ and $y_n$ must also converge to $L$. However, since $x_n$ is bounded above by $a$ it must converge to $L \le a$ and since $y_n$ is bounded below by $b$, it must converge to $L \ge b$. This is a contradiction since $L \le a < b \le L$ cannot hold.

Comment: I still cannot understand why $|S_{n+1} - S_n| > b-a > \epsilon$... can you explain a little bit

Comment: @SeanZhou Sure. If $S_n$ is even, then $S_n < a$, which means $S_{n+1}$ is odd and so $S_{n+1} > b$. Thus $S_{n+1} - S_n > b - S_n > b - a$. If $S_n$ is odd, then $S_n > b$ and $S_{n+1}$ is even and $S_{n+1} < a$. Thus $|S_{n+1} - S_n| = S_n - S_{n+1} > b - S_{n+1} > b-a$.